# core data - how to assign values of an attribute in core data to a variable

Tags: ios, core-data

Im experimenting with core data and I've been quite successful until now. Im trying to assign the core data values to variables of a class however Im having no luck! My entity is Player, the attributes are Team and Name. I want to assign the values of the attributes to variables of the Athlete class, and then assign these variable to labels in my controller. I only have one player currently in core data. I tried creating an NSManagedObject subclass of the entity (from reading answers on here however no luck).

THis is what I tried;

```
Athlete * myAthlete = [Athlete alloc];
Player * corePlayer = [Player alloc];
myAthlete.name = corePlayer.name;

NSLog(@"Player name %@",myAthlete.name);
```

And this is the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Player name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x832d960'
```

I apologies in advance because im sure im approaching the wrong way all together - i guess thats a part of learning.

Thanks.

****************EDIT1:***********************
here is my NSManagedObject class

```
//  Player.h



#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Player : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * team;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;


@end
```

and the .m

```
#import "Player.h"


@implementation Player

@dynamic team;
@dynamic name;


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an instance of a core data object, you need to store it in a managed object context, so alloc/init won't work.

You can create a new player instance like this:

```
Player *newPlayer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];
```

The exception you are getting is because there is no name property on the Player entity, that might be related to the initialisation but could be a different problem, you should post details of those classes as well.

Edit:

OK so to get an existing object you need to find it from a managed object context, rather than creating a new one. so given a managed object context which contains one Player, this code will fetch an array which contains one player object:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Player"];
NSArray *playerArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Then to access properties just get the player object:

```
Player *player = playerArray[0];
NSLog(@"team: %@", player.team);
NSLog(@"name: %@", player.name);
```

Comment: this is adding a null object to my Player entity

Comment: i don't know what you mean by that? is it returning nil?

Comment: No it is adding a new "Player" into core data, thats not what im looking for. Its inserting "null" for name and "null" for team. I looking for a way to fetch values from core Data and assign them to variables of a class. Sorry if i confused you

Comment: i edited my answer with some code that will fetch an existing player